# jQuery - change text AND value of option (select)

Tags: jquery, select

I just can't get this to work...

The text of the option is changed but the value remains untouched?

```
<select id="uid1485">
<option value="kein Bild">kein Bild</option>
<option value="Bild (2,50 Euro)">Bild (2,50 Euro)</option>
</select>


jQuery("#uid12").change(function(){
if (jQuery("#uid12").val() == "STAZ + Guller Kombi (3,00 Euro Aufschlag)") {

  jQuery("#uid1485 option[value='Bild (2,50 Euro)']").text("Bild (5,00 Euro)");
  jQuery("#uid1485 option[value='Bild (2,50 Euro)']").val("Bild (5,00 Euro)");

} else {



}
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose uid12 is also a dropdown?

Comment: Yes its also a dropdown.

Comment: Please provide HTML for `uid12`. Better yet, please create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: `<options>` tags actually are not elements, but rather attributes of the `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vZJFb/)?

Just change your if-condition to

`if ($("#uid12 option:selected").val() == "STAZ + Guller Kombi (3,00 Euro Aufschlag)")`

Comment: No:)

I've two pulldowns. When a specific value in the first pulldown is selected an specific option in the other pulldown has to be changed (val and text) - the if conition is working so far - the text of the option is correctly changed - but the value= attribute remains untouched...

Comment: I believe the value also changed, check the code of the fiddle in Firebug/Chrome Devtools. The value=Bild (2,50 Euro) changed to value=Bild (5,00 Euro)

Comment: Yes I see...Thank's a lot!...quite curious...i tought the if condition did work correctly ?!